# XCode Clean Build Folder CLI alternative

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm working on a `Cordova` app and I'm trying to correctly clear the cache (from `www` files) using CLI:

Inside XCode using the option key to perform a "Clean Build Folder" correctly clears the cache.

In the CLI, I've tried:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/folders/*
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
rm -rf $PROJECT_PATH/build
xcodebuild -project $PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -alltargets clean
xcodebuild -project $PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj -arch i386 -target $PROJECT_NAME -configuration Debug -sdk $SDK clean build VALID_ARCHS="i386" CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="$PROJECT_PATH/build"
```

But still I don't get updated `www`files in the simulator.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your commands seem to be okey.

There is an easy way to test - open the `.app` bundle (e.g. in `Finder`) and check the resources.

If the resources are okey and you still see old resources in the simulator, then reset the simulator and launch the app again.

If the resources in the app bundle are old, I recommend you to check `xcodebuild` output. I know it's long but with a simple search (`grep` or copy-paste to a text editor and search) you should be able to find out where do the resources come from.

Also make sure that you are really launching the built application, not an older version.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to clean the simulator, not your build environment.

Look at `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/` and subfolders to remove old installs of the app and app data from the simulator.